# Load aspx in div or adjust the size of an iframe

Tags: asp.net, javascript, iframe, html

I have an `htm` file with an `iframe` and a menu structure. The menu can load an `htm`  file in the `iframe` or an `aspx` file. No problem at all.

But... Now they want the `iframe` to get the size of its content. (So there will be no scrollbar in the `iframe`, but you have to scroll the whole `htm` file.)

I didn't get this to work so I thought I would use a `div` for this issue. But I can't get the `aspx` file to load in a `div`.

So I'm stuck. Either I have to find a way to let my `iframe` grow or I have to find a way to load an `aspx` file in a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Placing the remote content directly in a div will be the easiest here, otherwise you will have to try and automatically size the iframe after the page loads, and it might even change height after that too.

To load HTML content from a remote source into a div you will need to look at the XML HTTP Objects exposed to the browser via javascript.

It sounds like you are not familiar with the concept so I would advise using a Javascript library like [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) to help you along.